# Button alignment not working on real device android

Tags: android, xml

Is there anyone who can help me to find out what's wrong with my code? It's preview is as expected. but problem occurs just when I tested them in real device.I added Admob Banner ad at the bottom. before adding it it was completely okey. But now its not properly aligned.What is my mistake or what should I do?

My XML Code is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView8"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLink"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description_product"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_field_product"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Example application"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_fullwidth"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/choose_action"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    <view
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_fullwidth"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/abort_action"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Here My one button is aligned but another isn't it's place.How can I fix it?

**Current Status :** 
[image]

Comment: What do you want to align with Button ?

Comment: I just want to make btnProceed & btnCancel in a same row.

Comment: Could you show the picture you get now ?

Comment: @KeLiuyue please see my updated question.

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you  .I edited it for long time .@Tanvir Durlove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Set the content `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in the `LinearLayout`

2.make sure that `View`  is `gone` or `invisible` .And change to `View` .

3.If you want the two Button layout is half,you should set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` in `Button` .

**Edit**

Change the root tag to `LinearLayout`

Try this .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLink"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/description_product"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result_field_product"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Example application"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_fullwidth"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/choose_action"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_fullwidth"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/abort_action"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `layout_weight` you should set`layout_width` or `layout_height`to `0dp` depending on the `orientation`.

For eg. when you have `android:orientation="horizontal"` use `android:layout_width="0dp"`

and when you have `android:orientation="vertical"`use `android:layout_height="0dp"`